# How to catch event when an item in a BreadcrumbBar is clicked?

Tags: c#, wpf, event-handling, breadcrumbs

I'm testing BreadcrumbBar from [Vista Bridge Library](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/VistaBridge). My very simple demo project is [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6194904/BreadcrumBarTest.zip) (using latest version 1.4 at the moment). As we know, when clicking an item (on itself, not on the small breadcrumb on its tail), all the items on the right will disappear.

I want to pop up a message box when that happens. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got a better alternative [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/wpfbreadcrumb.aspx) from QuickZip.